# FOS User Bundle Throwing Error in Symfony 2.5

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I cannot get the FOS User Bundle to work in Symfony 2.5.  It's probably so simple I'm overlooking something basic.  I've used this bundle before without issues and cannot find a solution online.  I have everything set up and can't clear the cache -- I get this error.  It also displays the error on the browser.  Please be advised I am only a few weeks into learning Symfony!  I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) to the letter.

**Here is the error I receive:**

> InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "0, 1, 2" under
>   "fos_user"

What are the options "0, 1, 2" it is referring to?  I thought maybe it was a routing issue, failing to bring in a query variable but I'm not sure.

**Here is the relative part of `config.yml`:**

```
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yml }
  - { resource: security.yml }

fos_user:
  - db_driver: orm 
  - firewall_name: main
  - user_class: Main\Bundle\ToolsBundle\Entity\User
```

**Yes, it's registered in the `AppKernel.php`:**

```
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
```

**`User.orm.yml`:**

```
# Main/Bundle/ToolsBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml
Main\Bundle\ToolsBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: fos_user
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
```

**The `User.php` entity is straight from the demo:**

```
// Main/Bundle/ToolsBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Main\Bundle\ToolsBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `-` from `fos_user` config(`config.yml`). It should look like this:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Main\Bundle\ToolsBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't have enough reputation to vote up or anything, but that is the accepted answer.  Sorry for the delay in noticing your answer.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Got enough rep to up vote, thank you for your quick response, @pazulx!